# How to add "edoc" file type in Plupload

Tags: javascript, plupload

Does somebody know how to add the file type "edoc" to [Plupload](https://www.plupload.com/)?

I'm trying to do it in two ways, but nothing successful.

Both ways not working:

```js
filters: [
            { title: "Documents", extensions: "docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pdf,edoc" }
        ],
```

and using `mime_types`

```js
filters: {
            mime_types: [
                { title: "Documents", extensions: "docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pdf,edoc" },
            ]
        }
```